# How to handle repeating code in pig ( modularization )

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig code which does this,

connect to db1, do , connect to db2 and do same

union the outputs to produce final output

---

Basically how to handle cases where same code needed at multiple places in script(s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can define macros for the repeated operations and use these macros in your pig scripts like below:

```
DEFINE macroPerformUnion() RETURNS union_data {
    union_data = -- do your stuff
}
```

save above in a file with some name **macroPerformUnion.pig**

now to use your macro in scripts you need to import the pig file

```
IMPORT 'macroPerformUnion.pig';
```

and now you can call your macro using

```
union_data_result = macroPerformUnion();
```